# Jquery Mobile dialog on index 'pageinit' pops up everywhere

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm having trouble with a dialog on Jquery Mobile. On the index page I would like to have a dialog to the terms & conditions. The dialog works, I click accept and it goes away. Then when moving to another page it pops up again, and repeatedly pop's up even after clicking accept.

```
<script>
    $(document).bind('pageinit', function (){
        $.mobile.changePage("terms.html", "pop", false, false);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pageinit` is triggered when page a page is initialized. Because you used `$(document).bind('pageinit', function (){});` this means that you are binding to all pageinit's instead of just one. Use

```
$("#page1").bind('pageinit', function (){
     $.mobile.changePage("terms.html", "pop", false, false);
});
```

Where `page1` is the id of your first page.

Or

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function (){
    if(!termsAccepted) {
        $.mobile.changePage("terms.html", "pop", false, false);
    }
});
```

The second is better if you have multiple entry points into your app (like a mobile web page) as opposed to a single entry point (like a mobile app, always starts at index.html)

Edit: 
This might be even better

```
$(document).one('pageinit', function () {
    $.mobile.changePage("terms.html", "pop", false, false);
});
```